# SAS macro resolution call symputx (get current row)

Tags: macros, sas, rownum

I'm using SAS 9.2, and I got the following piece of code:

```
data success error;
length vague 3 path $150;
set foplist;
call symputx('error_count', rownum);
%if &&error&error_count = 0 %then %do;
path= "&&path&error_count";
vague=1;
output success;
%end;
%else %do;
...
%end;
run;
```

For each record I'd like to get the rownum, and combine it with another macro variable.
The rownum displays the rownumber of a record in the foplist dataset. For some reason I always get the last number in the dataset (probably because of macro compilation?)

For example:
A --- rownum=1
B --- rownum=2

I only get rownum=2

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create and resolve a macro variable within the same datastep.

Have you already defined the macro variables ERROR1-ERRORx and PATH1-PATHn and wish to retrieve those values into the datastep based on rownum? i.e. to resolve `&&ERROR&ERROR_COUNT`.

If so, just use symexist / symget...

```
data success error ;
  length vague 3 path $150 ;
  set foplist ;
  if symexist(cats('ERROR',rownum)) and symexist(cats('PATH',rownum)) then do ;
    error_count = symget(cats('ERROR',rownum)) ;
    if error_count = 0 then do ;
      path = symget(cats('PATH',rownum)) ;
      vague = 1 ;
      output success ;
    end ; 
    else output error ;
  end ;
  else output error ;
run;
```

Comment: Technically you can create an resolve a macro variable in a single data step:
call symput('VAR','1');
if symget('VAR') = '1' then put 'true';

But I am sure that Chris didn't mean precisely that.  He meant that you cannot call symput and then turn around and use &VAR in the same data set.  Quite true!

When you mix macro code %foo and &bar in with data step, imagine all of the macro code executing first - because that is essentially what SAS is doing.  Only after the %foo and &bar are resolved does SAS run your data step.

Comment: And anyway %if...%then... can not be used in open code as themselves (only within %macro...%mend wrap).